# Language cookie module not working in Safari?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, cookies

I use language_cookie module to safe the users preferred language with a cookie. E.g. The default site language is English. But i am from Holland so i want always the Dutch version of the site: http://landberg.at/nl. But the cookie is not working on Safari MAC?

In `Configuration » Regional and language » Languages` i have:

- **URL** (enabled)
- **Cookie** (enabled)
- **User** (enabled)

How can i make it work also for Safari?

(i use this module instead of IP redirect because with IP redirect you can not switch the language after you are redirected..? So the only solution in my opinion is to do it with a cookie. Or does somebody has another idea about this?).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should further verify/tune your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order you mentioned (= 'URL, Cookie, User') seems a bit strange to me. I.e. it'd be interesting to see what results you get by specifying "Cookie" BEFORE "URL" in your case.

Because with your current order, "Cookie" will only be used to select your preferred language if from the "URL" it's impossible to decide about which language should be shown. Though "User" is probably fine to leave it as the last one.